# Datas are not populated in Themed SELECT menu using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, append

I am Creating a web application with some templates, and now am stuck in populating the "SELECT" option.

Here am trying to populate using JavaScript...

But one problem is facing, when i used simple "SELECT" option, then i can see the datas in option menu.

But when i used the Themed "SELECT" menu, then the data are not populating....

I have tried a lot, but can't get the solution.

Please download the sample project [Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zzi2aypkncwsnjj/Demo.rar)

Please help me to solve this Issue...

Thanks and Regards,

Dileep.

Comment: i am not going to download that `rar`

Comment: Please post your code. What do you mean by "themed"? If you're using a plugin, what is it?

Comment: Instead of download..Make a fiddle

Comment: Here is the Fiddle Preview  http://jsfiddle.net/ZfLA6/6/

Comment: @MohammadAdil Here is the Fiddle Preview.....   http://jsfiddle.net/ZfLA6/6/

Comment: You might have to completely destroy the custom select box, then recreate it with the populated data and only after that re-initialize the custom style. I haven't looked at the code for this specific case, but the customization would need to support dynamically adding elements.

Comment: @Barmar Here is the Fiddle Preview.....   http://jsfiddle.net/ZfLA6/6/

Comment: @Lix Actually i have basic knowledge in javascript.. can u please gimme an example..??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZfLA6/10/